# Is it possible to suppress error message for a Symfony Validator?

Tags: php, symfony1

I'm using Symfony Validators to validate user name and password
on a form.

```
$this->setValidators(array(
  'username' => new sfValidatorEmail(),
  'password' => new sfValidatorString()
));
```

I'd like to **suppress** the `sfValidatorEmail`'s error message.  Its default error message is `Invalid.`

I have tried:

```
$this->setValidators(array(
  'username' => new sfValidatorEmail(Array(), array('invalid'=>'')),
  'password' => new sfValidatorString()
));
```

And also,

```
$this->setValidators(array(
  'username' => new sfValidatorEmail(Array(), array('invalid'=>NULL)),
  'password' => new sfValidatorString()
));
```

But neither seems to work.

Is this possible?  And if so, how can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly what and why you want to do it?